# Power BI get count of records based on measure within a certain range

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am able to do this with calculated columns, but I'm wondering if it can simplified with a measure. I have a table with tasks that includes a column for the due date of the task and created a measure to calculate how many days until the due date: `Days to Due Date = sumx('Data Submittals', datediff(TODAY(), 'Data Submittals'[Due Date], DAY))`; this works as expected.

I want to get the count of records where the measure is within a certain date range in the future (0-30 days, 30-60 days, 60-90 days, etc.); these date buckets are in a table with a min and max for each bucket. Is it possible to create a single measure that identifies the count for each bucket and then add the date bucket name and count (the new measure) into a table? Looking for something like this:

| Date Range | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 0 - 30 Days | 1 |
| 30 - 60 Days | 0 |
| 60 - 90 Days | 2 |
| 90+ Days | 2 |

I tried tweaking an example I saw using `RANKX` in a `CALCULATE`:

```
CALCULATE(count('Data Submittals'[Title]),
    FILTER(VALUES('Data Submittals'[Title]),
        COUNTROWS(FILTER('Date Groups',
            RANKX(ALL('Data Submittals'[Title]), [Days to Due Date],, DESC) > 'Date Groups'[Min] &&
            RANKX(ALL('Data Submittals'[Title]), [Days to Due Date],, DESC) <= 'Date Groups'[Max])
        )
    )
)
```

This gives me an incorrect count for the first two groups only (it's including tasks with due dates in the past). I also tried using an `IF` in a `COUNTX` (`COUNTX('Date Groups', if([Days to Due Date] > 'Date Groups'[Min] && [Days to Due Date] <= 'Date Groups'[Max], 1))`), but this doesn't return anything. I feel like I might be overthinking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
Count per day range := 
VAR _min = SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Date Groups'[Min] )
VAR _max = SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Date Groups'[Max] )
RETURN
COUNTROWS ( 
    FILTER (
        ALL ( 'Data Submittals' ) , 
        [Days to Due Date] > _min &&
        [Days to Due Date] <= _max
    )
)
```

Comment: That did it. Can you confirm my understanding of what's going on here? `ALL` removes any filters so all records in the table are being considered; where I have this in a table, `SELECTEDVALUE` only applies if I have the different buckets names (i.e., it can get the associated min and max for the bucket); and having all that in the `FILTER` sets the context for the `COUNTROWS`.

Comment: You are on the right track. Some nuances: `SELECTEDVALUE` returns a value if it is unique - typically at a row context or if functions like `VALUES` return one row. You can add a second argument in `SELECTEDVALUE` to override the `BLANK` return if it cannot find a unique value. `FILTER` creates a filtered table, where `ALL ( 'Data Submittals' )` is the table argument - and is exactly as you say. The other argument in `FILTER` is the actual filter, which will be the condition for which each row is evaluated in the filter.  `COUNTROWS` just counts rows of a table.